# Event bubble problem (I guess..!)

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

I have a big DIV #bigdiv. When I hover it, I want a small informative DIV #info to appear inside the big div. Problem: when I put my mouse on #info (once I made it appear by hovering #bigdiv) it makes it (#info) appear and disappear infinitely. Here's my code :

```
jQuery('#bigdiv').live("hover", function(){ 
    jQuery("#info").toggle();
});
```

**Update**

I tried mashappslabs's solution (mouseenter/mouseleave), and I tried T.J. Crowder's one (not to use live()) : same result.

In both cases the small div still shows up and disappear forever.

Comment: Can you post your html and css code. Your code works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/XZN5s/

Comment: @YNhat: Yes, that would be helpful. :-) I can replicate similar behavior with the example linked from my answer, but only @glabus can tell us whether that's also the behavior he/she is seeing.

Comment: @dandan @glabus: then some other part of your code is not doing the right thing, this example I posted for you works http://jsfiddle.net/2aCJ2/, look at the code there CSS, HTML and jQuery combined and maybe post more of your code here if you need further help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a minor bug in the `live` version of `hover`. Contrast [this example](http://jsbin.com/oxaga5/), using `live`, with [this one](http://jsbin.com/oxaga5/2) using an event handler actually on `bigdiv` (the counter is there so we know when things are changing). The issue is when you move the mouse into the `info` div (the word "info") and out of it (still within `bigdiv`). So the answer may be not to use `live`, although I'm guessing you have a reason for using `live` and so that may be inconvenient.

You may know that `hover` is basically just a combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (which are IE-specific events, but jQuery emulates them on browsers that don't provide them). But `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` don't bubble; that's part of why they're useful. The related (and not IE-specific) `mouseover` and `mouseout` events bubble, though, so this looks like it <s>might be</s> is a bug in the `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` emulation that's specific to delegated handling. (**Edit:** Specifically, [bug #9069](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9069), which has already been reported and is being actively worked on.)

Comment: What browser are you using? Both examples work perfectly for me (FF 4.0.1, Linux)

Comment: @nico: Be sure to move your mouse over the word info and out again (but still within the box). I've tried Chrome 10, Firefox 3.6, Opera 11 on Linux and IE6 and IE7 on Windows.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: ok, now I see the problem. I misunderstood the original question.

Comment: @nico: *Maybe*. Until/unless @glabus comes back, we don't really know. :-)

Comment: @TJCrowder: my impression was he was saying that the small div continued to showed up and disappear forever. However, you found an interesting bug anyways ;)

Comment: @nico: Yeah. :-) I figured it was some vagary of where his mouse was when the div appeared, making the div appear under his mouse and trigger the handler, which made it disappear, which made it appear... But I can't get my example to do that, so maybe not.

Comment: @nico: Turns out it's a reported bug, [bug #9069](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9069).

Answer (score 0):

@glabus

make #info position absolute

```
#info{
position:absolute;
top: 20px;
left:40px;
}
```

you can dynamically set top and left with jquery.css also

Comment: He shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: ...and in my example I don't. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseenter and mouseleave, check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/2aCJ2/ and here is the code:
CSS:

```
#big {width: 500px; height:500px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px;}
#info {display: none; border: 2px solid #ddd;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="big">
 <div id="info">
    <p>Hello I'm visible</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#big")
.mouseenter(function(e) {
    $("#info").show();
})
.mouseleave(function(e) {
    $("#info").hide();
});
```

Hope it helps. Cheers